# Facebook Like Box feed only shows when logged out

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, feed

Facebook Like Box feed is empty despite there being many post by the page, or only shows posts when logged out of Facebook.

In one case the feed only shows posts made on the iPhone with location info (despite these being months older) and shows no other posts. It does this not only on the website were I have the feed embedded, but on FB's dev page preview where the like box code is generated.
This problem exists the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

So two solutions to this problem.

Note: not all FB pages are alike. Selective rollouts of new FB features are applied to certain pages progressively or by creation date. Thus why this problem doesn't appear in all pages.

Two causes for this feed problem:

1. Being logged in as an admin can cause the feed to not show all posts. Thus the problem doesn't exist for non-admins. Logging in as a non-admin or without any FB login at all shows the feed normally as it should be.
   (in one case I worked with, only posts made by iPhone with Location info would show to admins, while all non-admins saw every post for the page).
2. Feed inactivity. If no posts have been made in a certain amount of time(I don't have an exact timeframe) the feed will show nothing, not even the "Show More" drop down. On one project (observed in Feb-March 2012), simply creating a new post fixed it instantly. Not sure how permanent or temporary this glitch is, or whether FB is/has fixed it.

Also, not sure what (if any) correlation this problem might have to linked twitter, tumblr etc accounts.